# How to prevent html injection in Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sanitization

I want to prevent users to enter html injection to textbox. I have researched some example but they are generally about allowing html tags through pipes and saying ***angular automatically sanitizes html tags***. But in my example when I enter `<script>alert('blabla')</script>` to text box, it is accepted and registered to db like this..

How can I prevent it ?

My template code is:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
          <mat-form-field fxFlex="20">
            <input matInput name="label" [(ngModel)]="product.label" placeholder="Label"
                   required>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

and my ts file is:

```
import { Product } from '../../../';

@Component({
  selector: '....',
  templateUrl: '....',
  styleUrls: ['....']
})
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {

  product: Product = <Product>{};

  constructor(some services etc.) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

   //some code
  }
```

**Note again:** I want to prevent entering html script injection, not allowing it with bypass or pipe...

Comment: I have deleted wrong part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use DomSanitizer for that

```
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser"
import { SecurityContext } from "@angular/core";

constructor(private sanit:DomSanitizer){
  var dom = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, "<script> alert('HELLO'); </script>");
  console.log(dom);
}
```

if it returns null, then it was an issue with html,else it returns passed html

Comment: where is my ngModel product.label etc. its like hello is hardcoded. ? And there is syntax error in there about saint:Domsanitizer is not used

Comment: and I want to prevent html script entering not allowing html.